# Is there free software that can convert serial input messages to TCP/IP packets?

Tags: ethernet, tcpip, serial-port, serial

There is a serial port that can receive text messages from the external device. Now I want to pass these messages to a special software. But that software can only receive TCP/IP packet. For example, I can use telnet to connect it and send the text messages. Will I emulate a NIC device? Is there free software or commercial software that can do such things?

Comment: What OS?  This would be fairly straightforward on linux.

Comment: I use Windows now.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume linux.

First you need to identify your serial connection, usually these are of the form `/dev/ttyS0`.  Using `dmesg | grep tty` should help find it.

Next you want to set the speed of the serial connection - 9600, 8n1 is common:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600 cs8 -parenb -cstopb
```

Now you can read the tty with `cat /dev/ttyS0`, however we want to direct anything coming in via the tty to a tcp connection.  To do this we will use `netcat`:

```
sudo apt-get install netcat     # this is debian style package management, yours may differ
```

Now assuming your software is listening on IP address 192.168.10.1 on port 3322, we will direct the output from `cat` to `nc`, which is netcat, which will connect and pass the incoming traffic to the service:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 | nc 192.168.10.1 3322
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ser2net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ser2net/)

ser2net provides a way for a user to connect from a network connection to a serial port.